# Google Maps with Rails 3 multiple markers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I am trying to build a complex google maps application with Rails as the framework. I have seen the YM4R gem and others that supposedly help with google maps development, but I honestly just want to go without them for now.

How can I get it so that rails passes a huge list of points to my google maps view, and the google maps javascript plots all of the points? I understand I probably need to use json somewhere (such as render :json => @points), but when I place that in my controller, I get an Illegal Action error from WEBbrick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at my gem:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

And for an example of an customization see [Google Maps, Ruby on Rails, Zoom level with one marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821997/google-maps-ruby-on-rails-zoom-level-with-one-marker)