# How to get the id field and send to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'd like to know how can I get the ID field from my Model to pass in the JavaScript that I call when I click in a marker.

My model:

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false, :lat => "lat", :lng => "lon"
```

My controller

```
def index
    @locales_markers = Locale.all.to_gmaps4rails
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  { render :layout => false }
    end
end
```

My View

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => { "data" => @locales_markers } %>

<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script>
        Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', function(){
                    $('#info').load('/messages/' **<HERE I'D LIKE TO PASS THE ID>**);
                    $('#info').dialog("open");
                });

            }
        };
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Thanks,
Luciano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every marker property is stored and can be retrieved.

In your example, simply do:

```
$('#info').load('/messages/' + Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].id );
```

EDIT:

You should create another js function:

```
custom_listener = function(the_id) {
  return function(){
        $('#info').load('/messages/' + the_id );
        $('#info').dialog("open");
  };
};
```

And call it this way:

```
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
 for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', custom_listener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].id));
  }
};
```

Comment: I'd already tried this way and happens this erro: **Gmaps4Rails.markers[i] is undefined**.
I believe that it´s happens because the context of variable.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my controller to:

```
  def index
    @locales_markers = Locale.all.to_gmaps4rails do |locale|
      "\"id\": \"#{locale.id}\""
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  { render :layout => false }
    end
  end
```

and work fine, but, I'm not able to get the id value in the view.

How to solve it?

Thanks,
Luciano