# js error when trying to dynamically update gmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Trying to get gmaps to update in place once a new location is typed out. (anyone know a good tutorial for this actually? :P)

Anyways when running the Gmaps4Rails.replaceMarkerst method, I seem to bring up a js error seen when using chrome's inspection tool as seen below. any ideas?

http://stuff.saikonet.org/images/misc/2011-07-22-030217_1024x768_scrot.png

Comment: well, could you give me more context? You were replacing how many markers by how many markers?

Comment: I tried several settings without being able to reproduce the bug. Please provide your code.

Comment: I tried replacing no markers with one, using this:

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
          Gmaps4Rails.replaceMarkers([{"lng": "-92.5294574", "lat": "45.1969796"}])
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok gotcha, your problem is not the `replace_marker` function.

Indeed, using the good old document-ready buddy, the google maps isn't yet created. So yep everything is failing.

That's where `Gmaps4Rails.callback` makes it's entry.

**After** the declaration of your map (for an obvious reason: Gmaps4Rails must be defined):

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script>
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
  Gmaps4Rails.replaceMarkers([{"lng": "-92.5294574", "lat": "45.1969796"}]);
};
</script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: nice ;). only thing now is that when it replaces the markers it messes up my zoom and is super close-in.. how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: hm.. actually turning off auto_adjust no longer centers it around the marker now, I just don't want it to zoom in all the way. any way to achieve that?

Comment: you'll find the answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821997/google-maps-ruby-on-rails-zoom-level-with-one-marker

Comment: :) you know what rewards then (and please, no death note!)

Comment: hahahahah.

anyways :P. I'm also getting an unknown method error when trying to use adjust_map_to_bounds();. has this function been renamed or something similar?

Comment: hm gauging from the other post you linked I assumed adjustMapToBounds would center in on the marker but doesn't really seem to have any effect

Comment: it depends on the value of `Gmaps4Rails.map_options.auto_adjust`

Comment: yay I got it!! :P. only if every plugin maintainer was like you lol

Comment: google's API has changed, that's why... ask a new question if you don't find yourself in google's doc

Comment: I'm getting another no method error when using Gmaps4Rails.geocode.. has that been renamed too?

Comment: ohh it's a rails method not javascript. thankies once again :P

Comment: hm having it in rails instead of js actually complicates things quite a bit. is there no js equivalent? I'm basically trying to update the map as the user is typing in the text field, and not sure how to integrate a rails method into that....

Comment: this is basically what I'm trying to get at:

Gmaps4Rails.replaceMarkers(Gmaps4Rails.geocode($('#location').val()))

Comment: or even clicking a button to update is ok instead (sending info to a controller and back) but then that's rails code and I can't get a javascript variable into that :/. is there no way to update the map with a user-specified location without reloading the whole page?

Comment: ah wait no I think I have a way with the sending info to a controller method.

Comment: still kind of messy though.. would be nice to have geocoding available through js