# Adjust Zoom Gmaps4Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using the Gmaps4Rails gem and cannot figure out how to adjust the default zoom settings.  In my view I have the following code:

```
<%= gmaps({
   "map_options" => {"auto_adjust" => false, "auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 15 },
   "markers"     => {"data" => @json }
  })
%>
```

I know this has been asked and answered many times, but maybe I'm just not seeing something...any advice? Am i missing something completely obvious?  I apologize for reposting this question.

Thanks, Kevin

*EDIT*

I failed to properly comment out the default instance of gmaps and it overrode my customized settings.  Thanks for all the help @apneadiving!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're simply missing that seeing the whole map means providing a very small number, not a big one!

```
<%= gmaps({
  "map_options" => {"auto_adjust" => false, "zoom" => 0 },
  "markers"     => {"data" => @json }
 })
%>
```

Comment: Hmm...I wasn't sure about the zoom number, so I tried it with a bunch of different values.  No numbers seem to change the zoom value.  Is there some other setting that may be overriding this custom setting?

Comment: ok, I misunderstood your question, sorry. This is rally weird. Nothing overrides the zoom level once you disable the `auto_adjust`, unless you define some manual `bounds` in `map_options`...You don't have any error in console?

Comment: in console: does `Gmaps4Rails.map.getZoom` change ?

Comment: nope, no errors, i just altered the infowindow for example and it worked flawlessly, its just this zoom level that i'm stuck at.  only thing i changed is the size of the map in `#gmaps4rails_map {
 width: 770px;
 height: 500px;
}`

Comment: i type Gmaps4Rails.map.getZoom(x) where x is a number and get back 21...not sure what that means.  the map does not change when i pass in any values in the console, it stays at the current zoom level.

Comment: getZoom doesn't take any args, it's just here to see the current zoom level

Comment: i type it in the console in Chrome and when i pass an argument it returns the maps current zoom level only if i pass an argument, but i have to manually zoom in/out the map for those values to change.  if i don't pass any argument i get the following: `function (){return this.get(a)}`

Comment: `Gmaps4Rails.map.getZoom()` without arg :)

Comment: Gmaps4Rails.map.getZoom() returns the maps current zoom level, yes...sorry.  the value only changes when i manually zoom in/out then reenter Gmaps4Rails.map.getZoom() in the console

Comment: please joint the chat, will be easier

Answer (score 10):

I'm on gmaps4rails 1.3.2 and these are the best settings I could find:

```
<%= gmaps({
  "map_options" => {"auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 10 },
  "markers" => {"data" => @json }
})
%>
```

- I did not set `auto_adjust` to `false`, because the map would not be centered on the marker anymore.
- The `10` value for the zoom is nice to display approximatively a 50km-wide map.

Answer (score 2):

what helped me in this case was this:

```
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
    setTimeout("Gmaps4Rails.map.setZoom(13);", 100);
};
```