# Google-maps-for-Rails without a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

Sorry to be newbie, but i wanna draw your attention to my problem while using gmaps4rails - great gem.

In my app there is no database backend. Actually i just want to collect markers like this:

```
<% markers=[]%>
<% @search.each do |dish| %>
<% if (not dish.restaurant.nil?)
    restaurant=Restaurant.where( :id  => dish.restaurant["Id"])
    markers<< {:longitude => restaurant.lng , :latitude=> restaurant.lat}
  end%>
<div id="dish_listed"><%= render 'dish_listed',  :dish => dish %></div>
<% end %>
<%= gmaps4rails(markers.to_json) %>
```

Unfortunately it displays a gray rectangular whithout a map *(
I`ve managed to follow the steps from [Wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki) (i did it several times *))))

When i do

```
markers.to_json
```

i get

```
"[{\"longitude\":"30.252442359924316",\"latitude\":"59.92999013067258"}]"
```

And i have no idea why kind of code

```
<%= gmaps4rails('[{\"lng\":"30.252442359924316",\"lat\":"59.92999013067258"}]') %>
```

doesnt work? Where should it be initialized? Or what magic steps did i forget? I also forked a [project](https://github.com/thasuresh/gmaps_project/) by thasuresh. Started it and the removed everything from the model, and pushed my markers there, and it displayed me just what i wanted.

But i still cant reach the same result on the project i write by my self!!!

```
-----And now i`m sitting here and waiting for flying tomatos *)))-----
```

PS
rails 3.1rc5
gmaps4rails 0.10.2

BTW Could it be no gmappable model?

Comment: Seems like using the JavaScript maps API would be a good use here. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html It would remove the layer of abstraction that you have with the gmaps4rails gem and allow you to draw upon the examples that Google provides.

Comment: While trying to figure out what`s the problem it occured that I can`t initialize gmap properely! Once i`ve created a scaffold and followed the steps from the Wiki. One map initialized, and afterwards another one might be opened. So how should  i properly initialize gmaps4rails?

Comment: It might be a number of issues, thats the problem. Without knowing more I dont see the need for you to use gmaps4rails without a database backend. You can use google maps using their normal JS library, is that undesireable for any reason?

Comment: @Devin M Its the third day i`m braking down with this problem, it seemed easyer to use a couple of lines of rubycode instead of dozens lines of js. But if i won`t suceed with this I`ll follow your recommendations

Comment: If you need help with the JS api let me know with a reply to this and a link to your new question. I am happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
<%= gmaps4rails('[{"lng":"30.252442359924316","lat":"59.92999013067258"}]') %>
```

There are still little fixes to do for Rails 3.1, some threads are open on github.

To adjust the zoom level with one marker, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821997/google-maps-ruby-on-rails-zoom-level-with-one-marker).

Comment: Thanks for coming! Yes, but no! It only outputs  code <div id="map_container"><div id="gmaps4rails_map"></div> code It seems like initializing wasn`t called, or failed! It only works when i have an object that acts_as_gmappable - but i din`t have a db-backend *) I`m new to rails so i appreciate your patience *)))) PS no problem with zoom. I simply have no map *(

Comment: Just checked all opened issues on github, downgraded to rails

Comment: Do you have all js files inside your view? any code visible on github or elsewhere?

Comment: Just checked opened issues on github, downgraded to rails 3.0.9 and gmaps4rails 0.9.1, but still the same problem. I have to call some gmappable model.to_gmaps4rails in the controller to get this working. server log is ok . On GitHub it is [here](https://github.com/IvanShamatov/something-secret) and gmpas4rails is called at the begining of food.html.erb view. PS Sorry for the mess inside.

Comment: see working app after changes here: https://github.com/apneadiving/something-secret/commit/b8cfcbb943eb16c9adeec89bd49be3d4cea2a028

Comment: wowwwowow! How did you do that!!! I`ve applied your changes and it magickally works. I thought i tried it 10 times at least! You must be a mage*)))

Comment: thank you so much!!! As soon as i earn "enough carma" i`ll do a +1 but now i only can accept *) May i repost the complete answer? the trick was to use `code          <%= gmaps({
                "map_options" => { "auto_zoom" => false},
                "markers"     => { "data" => @markers.to_json }
               })
         %>`

Comment: Ok, I see. As you feel for the answer. The only point was to upgrade the gem. Other stuff is for zoom