# gmaps4rails single marker auto zoom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am trying to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821997/google-maps-ruby-on-rails-zoom-level-with-one-marker) to zoom out a bit (by default) when a single marker is displayed on the map. I have tried the code below, and have a working map generating, but changing setZoom has no effect. Also, I receive the following error from firebug (below code).

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"auto_zoom" => false} }) %>

<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      function gmaps4rails_callback() {
        if (Gmaps4Rails.markers.length == 1) {
         //only one marker, choose the zoom level you expect
         Gmaps4Rails.map.setZoom(5);
        }
        else{
         //more than one marker, let's auto_zoom
         Gmaps4Rails.map_options.auto_zoom = true;
         Gmaps4Rails.adjust_map_to_bounds();
        }
      }
    </script>
<% end %>
```

The only error says:

```
TypeError: Yc is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...=b}Rf[F].Fa=xk(7,Yc("f"));me[F].cb=xk(3,function(a){var b;if(b=a.ca[ec]()?j:a.ca...
```

Comment: what version of the gem do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the interface changed a lot since I posted the answer you quote.

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"auto_zoom" => false} }) %>

<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
        if (Gmaps.map.markers.length == 1) {
         //only one marker, choose the zoom level you expect
         setTimeout(function() { Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setZoom(5);}, 50);
        }
        else{
         //more than one marker, let's auto_zoom
         Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_zoom = true;
         Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
        }
      }
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and for the gem. Only problem is when I try the above code I get TypeError: Gmaps.map.adjust_map_to_bounds is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

Gmaps.map.adjust_map_to_bounds();

find_map (line 289)

TypeError: Yc is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

...=b}Rf[F].Fa=xk(7,Yc("f"));me[F].cb=xk(3,function(a){var b;if(b=a.ca[ec]()?j:a.ca...

Comment: I changed this line Gmaps.map.adjusMapToBounds(); to add the 't' in adjust.. and I was able to run the callback without any errors in the console.. However, still no glory on setZoom ... with only one marker showing I wasn't able to modify setZoom.. Always set to max zoom, no matter what :(

Comment: For now I have just decided to add an extra marker into every json variable with json = json[0..-2] << ",{\"description\":\"Your Location:<br /><b>#{params[:location][:address]}</b>\",\"title\":\"Your Location\", \"width\":37, \"picture\":\"http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png\", \"shadow_picture\":\"http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png\", \"shadow_anchor\":[12, 35], \"shadow_width\":100, \"shadow_height\":100, \"id\":\"\",\"lat\":#{location.latitude},\"lng\":#{location.longitude}}]"

Comment: mmm, and without your additional marker, what do you have when you add `console.log(Gmaps.map.markers.length)` to the callback?

Comment: So you confirm `Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setZoom(5);` is executed?

Comment: Well, if I put alert(); just below Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setZoom(5);  then I see the alert.. so the if statement is running properly, but Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setZoom(5) seems to have no effect. How can I test that the command is executed?

Comment: By the way, I dumped my Gmaps.map.serviceObject after setZoom and saw xh
A: V
C: rh
__e3_: Object
ac: Nf
b: HTMLDivElement
bc: Gf
center: O
controls: Array[14]
disableDefaultUI: false
disableDoubleClickZoom: false
draggable: true
e: Gf
features: V
gm_accessors_: Object
gm_bindings_: Object
mapTypeControl: undefined
mapTypeId: "roadmap"
mapTypes: Tf
maxZoom: null
minZoom: null
n: Uf
overlayMapTypes: Nf
re: Gf
se: Gf
streetView: rh
tilt: 0
ve: Gf
zoom: 21
__proto__: c

Comment: google maps is busy processing the bounds and literally ignores the setZoom, the solution is to use a mere timeout, see edit

Comment: You are one of the best devs out there! Thanks for the dedicated support. You the man!

Comment: Quick question if I may.  Using this exact code, I get nada.  console shows `Gmaps.map.markers.length = 0`, but there is clearly a single marker created.

Comment: @apneadiving, it happens sometimes that 50 ms timeout isn't enough.

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev yep, I ended up using an event on the map directly, observing idle state

Comment: It's been another 2 years since this answer, is there a more up to date syntax using `handler`? The wiki could use some examples and a page clean up.

Comment: @Archonic the wiki's homepage clearly link old documentation as old documentation (Gmaps4rails before v2). Reading the wiki, you may have noticed there are plenty of examples: http://apneadiving.github.io/

Comment: Awesome! I was using google and stumbled on the old docs not realizing it. Thanks!