# Gmaps4rails too close zoom when showing single marker

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gmaps4rails single marker auto zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658748/gmaps4rails-single-marker-auto-zoom)

I am using gmaps4rails with Google Maps API v3 and often display a single marker. gmaps4rails then zooms in, in order that all markers – here 1 – are visible on the map. 
However, it takes the closest zoom level available in Google Maps and I haven't found a way to change the zoom level for this single marker only.

I am displaying my maps like this:

```rb
gmaps(markers: {data: @events, options: {raw: '{animation: 
google.maps.Animation.DROP}'}}, map_options: {auto_adjust: 
true, center_on_user: true, auto_zoom: true, zoom: 14})
```

The marker is replaced with `Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it that for setting an custom zoom yor auto_zoom should be false.

I use this setting to get my custom zoom:

> gmaps(:map_options => {"auto_zoom" => false,  "zoom" => 17}, :markers
>   => { "data" => @json })

Hope this helps.